# How I can animate a 3D render on scroll using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I was thinking to make an animated 3D render on scroll like [this one](https://www.apple.com/airpods-pro/) on the apple website. Inspecting the elements, it's clear that the faux 3D effect is made using hundred of images, each image representing one particular frame.

[image: frames]

Looking for the best approach to replicate this amazing effect, I found this library, [lottie](https://lottiefiles.com), that is a framework developed by airbnb that takes the render, use a plugin on adobe after effects and create a final JSON file containing the animation. Doesn't convince me though, since it's not clear how to incorporate the final JSON file in your own JavaScript code, without using other frameworks.

There're thousand of libraries for animate html elements based on user scroll, but none of these support a 'change of frame'. The question is, what is in your opinion the best approach to obtain a similar result, have you ever made anything similar?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this one : https://youtu.be/wLUJ9VNzZXo

It splits into frames and disply according to scroll using scroll magic.

```
const intro = document.querySelector(".intro");
const video = intro.querySelector("video");
const text = intro.querySelector("h1");
//END SECTION
const section = document.querySelector("section");
const end = section.querySelector("h1");

//SCROLLMAGIC
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

//Scenes
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: 9000,
  triggerElement: intro,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .addIndicators()
  .setPin(intro)
  .addTo(controller);

//Text Animation
const textAnim = TweenMax.fromTo(text, 3, { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0 });

let scene2 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: 3000,
  triggerElement: intro,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .setTween(textAnim)
  .addTo(controller);

//Video Animation
let accelamount = 0.1;
let scrollpos = 0;
let delay = 0;

scene.on("update", e => {
  scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 1000;
});

setInterval(() => {
  delay += (scrollpos - delay) * accelamount;
  console.log(scrollpos, delay);

  video.currentTime = delay;
}, 33.3);
```

Comment: I saw this video, unfortunately is not what I'm looking for.